# Disable read operation ont the slave member for a mongodb replicaset

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

`rs.slaveOk()` enables read operation on the slave member in a MongoDB replica set.

What function is used to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Simply type `rs.slaveOk(false)`.

In the shell you can see what is the code that is executed for each command, so if you tipe `rs.slaveOk` (without parenthesis) what you get is the following:

```
rs.slaveOk
function (value) {
    return db.getMongo().setSlaveOk(value);
}
```

So `slaveOk` is actually a function that accepts the boolean parameter and recalls `setSlaveOk`, which is composed by the following code:

```
db.getMongo().setSlaveOk
function (value) {
    if (value == undefined)
        value = true;
    this.slaveOk = value;
}
```

As you see, `setSlaveOk` has `true` as default value, so by specifying false you can prevent reading from the secondary.

EDIT: as correclty stated by dAm2K in the comment below, `rs.slaveOk` has been deprecated from version 4.4 of MongoDB; just use `rs.secondaryOk`.

Comment: just to say that rs.slaveOk() is now deprecated in favor of rs.secondaryOk()